# MySQL: How to filter date of format 2011-11-29 19:30:00 and extract the month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am trying to `extract` the `month` from the date string `2011-11-29 19:30:00` using MySQL.

I have tried `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as d` to no avail, and also `STR_TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date), '%Y-%m-%d') AS d` also with no joy.

Can anyone suggest the proper method to `extract` the month from such a string and `group` by it?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Is it a `DATETIME` column or a `VARCHAR`? And what was your result with `EXTRACT`?

Comment: It's a string so not a DATETIME variable, just a VARCHAR. Wouldn't of thought it would have mattered what variation of text field it was beyond it wasn't an actual mysql date structure?

Comment: a DATETIME is not a text field, so yes, it should matter. Try [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: @fab that is what I said, and what I put in my answer 'beyond it wasn't an actual mysql date'...

Comment: It was not clear from your question, that's why I asked. But I see you found the STR_TO_DATE solution by yourself, great :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
 select DATE_FORMAT('2011-11-29 19:30:00', '%c');
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUBSTRING(date_string,6,2)`?

x

Answer (score 1):

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE(date_ordered, '%Y-%m-%d')) as month
```

seemed to work well

Answer (score 0):

You can get day from datetime field as like following

```
DATE_FORMAT( date , '%d' ) AS d
```